# How to enter list of tags longer than 1024 characters in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy

How can I increase maximum limit of characters for tags field? or any other "Entity reference" field

The problem is, when I create content I can not enter keywords in that field once I have reached 1024 characters in total.

Found this limit in file "core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php"

```
'#maxlength' => 1024,
```

How can I override it? not changing the core files.

Comment: Can you give us more context? What steps did you take to produce this? Do you get an error message, if yes, which one? What is tags field exactly? A vocabulary?

Comment: I do not get error, because it do not let me enter more than 1024 characters in that field, when i create content. But when I edit already published content with 1024 characters in tags field, drupal adds (taxonomy term id) next to each tag, so length of the field become longer than 1024, and now i get error when i try to save it "Tags cannot be longer than 1024 characters but is currently XXXX characters long.". My tags field is taxonomy term reference to default drupal tags vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8:

```
 function MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

      if ($context['widget']->getPluginId() == 'entity_reference_autocomplete') {
        if ($element['target_id']['#maxlength'] == 1024) {
          $element['target_id']['#maxlength'] = 3072;
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: `hook_field_widget_form_alter` is deprecated in drupal:9.2.0 and is removed from drupal:10.0.0. Use `hook_field_widget_single_element_form_alter` instead.